# If Statement not runing inside setter

Tags: javascript

im fairly new to programing (about a week lol), but here is a boiled down peice of script i wrote, and i cant seem to get it to output correctly. for the number of students, there is an if statement that i placed inside the corresponding setter. no matter what i do, if seems that the if statement just gets bypassed. not sure whats happening but ive been staring at this for like an 2 hours now and re written it 3 times. can someone explain what im doing wrong>

```
class School {
    constructor(numberOfStudents){

      this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
    }

    get numberOfStudents(){ return this._numberOfStudents}
    set numberOfStudents(value){ 
      if(typeof value !== 'string'){
        this._numberOfStudents = value
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.')
      }
    } 
  };

  const highSchool = new School('many');
  console.log(highSchool.numberOfStudents);
```

also to note; i belive the output should be this as the variable inputed is a 'string'

```
console.log('Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.')
```

Comment: `typeof i` probably should be `typeof value`

Comment: Nothing in your code sets `. numberOfStudents` so nothing will call the setter

Comment: try `this.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;` in the constructor

Comment: You are not making use of your setter. this.numberOfStudents is how you can get or set the `_numberOfStudents` variable

Answer (score -1):

```js
class School {
  constructor(numberOfStudents) {
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }

  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents;
  }
  set numberOfStudents(value) {
    if (typeof value !== "string") {
      this._numberOfStudents = value;
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.");
    }
  }
}

const highSchool = new School("many");

// The setter is triggered when the value is changed
highSchool.numberOfStudents = 'new value' // Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.

console.log(highSchool.numberOfStudents);
```

Comment: if you put `this.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;` then the code will work as intended